# Confused with my CSS layout

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
<div id="sbr">
    <div id="sbr_bdy">
        <div id="sbr_lnk">
            <div><a>test</a></div>
            <div><a>test</a></div>
            <div><a>test</a></div>
            <div><a>test</a></div>
            <div><a>test</a></div>
            <div><a>test</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
#sbr_lnk a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 180px;
}

#sbr { width: 200px; background-color: pink; }

#sbr_lnk div {
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#sbr_lnk {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

What I would like to see is that:

1) sbr_lnk serves as a background for all the inner DIVs and As. Right now it doesn't go from top to bottom:
2) The DIVs inside sbr_lnk have 10px space on the right and left
3) The As have curved corners and fit just inside the DIVs.

I have tried a lot of combinations but I think my big problem is with sbr_lnk. It does not seem to be working as a background DIV. Help would be much appreciated.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ttyT/)
 the inner address link is a rectangle with rounded corners that's 10px inside of the

Comment: I didnt quite understand what it is that you want.. could you maybe produce example image that shows what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You have too many styled applied to the `<a>` tag.

Move some styles to the wrapper divs and it will look as you desire.

```
#sbr_lnk div {
    height: 25px;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

[See the example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/7ttyT/16/).

Answer (score 0):

Could also be done like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7ttyT/34/ in order to keep the style to the  tag for reusability's sake, with multiple a's in one div.